# HttpCookieManager.SetCookie throws an exception

Tags: c#, cookies, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In my Windows Store app (8.1), two consequent requests are sent to a server.

The first request is "https://a.b.com/ssologon", which gets a response from the server and an `LtpaToken2` cookie is set to the app's cookies via the [Set-Cookie header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384321(v=vs.85).aspx) in the response.

This cookie looks like this

> {LtpaToken2=base64StringReturnedFromServer;Path=/;Domain=a.b.com}

And before the 2nd request ("https://a.b.com/logon") is sent, I call the [HttpCookieManager.SetCookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298675.aspx) API to set the `LtpaToken2` cookie again- which is already in the cookies, but this line throws an exception.

```
filter.CookieManager.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("LtpaToken2", "a.b.com", "/") {Value = base64StringReturnedFromServer});
```

The exception is generic and not quite informative:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Windows.Web.winmd
>
> Additional information: The operation identifier is not valid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800710DD)

More information on this exception:

1. It only happens to `LtpaToken2`, in fact, there is another cookie, `LtpaToken`, which can be freely set without throwing the exception.
2. It looks like it only happens if the domain I am trying to set is an exact match of the domain of the existing cookie. If I set it as **.b.com**, or **s.a.b.com**, it is OK.

What does the error message "The operation identifier is not valid." mean?

Comment: I try my best to reproduce your issue, but you could refer to [this document](https://sites.google.com/site/howcanyouspeeduppc/the_operation_identifier_is_not_valid_troubleshooter) to know What does the error message "The operation identifier is not valid." mean.

Comment: The link you provided is not even remotely relevant.

Comment: Hi, @kennyzx Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @alminh No. This can only be reproduced with an internal server of my company, I have contacted MS but failed to recreate this issue.

Comment: @kennyzx Ok, thank you anyway for the update!